# Empty homedir name when SSHing to localhost

Tags: ssh, cygwin, hadoop, home-directory, cygwin-sshd

I am trying to start a system (Hadoop, but that should not matter much for this question), and need to be able to ssh to localhost. I do this on windows with cygwin. The cygwin SSHD service is running, and ssh localhost works (as does ssh username@localhost). However, when I do, it says:

```
Could not chdir to home directory : No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory
  could not be created.
Setting HOME to /tmp.
```

Somehow it tries to chdir to an directory with an empty name, which fails. However, I do not see why it would do that. The /home/username folder exists like it should, and is accessible after logging in over ssh.

Any pointers on where ssh would get the empty folder name from? (some configuration I don't know about maybe?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Has the user got a home directory set? (you can check via `grep user /etc/passwd`, or `echo $HOME`)

Comment: @qweet: good one, $HOME is set, but the entry in /etc/passwd is empty for the user. Can I just add the path in there?

Comment: Better to use `usermod`- the command is `usermod -d /some/directory/wherever user`.

Comment: @qweet: that indeed solves the problem (I guess it was quite a noob question....). Only problem is that now it suddenly needs a password, but probably I can disable that somewhere.... If you add your answer as a real answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Password? For logging in or for making the change? If its the change then doing prepending a `sudo` will force it to work, and if it's the latter, it's because you now have a home directory and your settings are no longer in /tmp (you might want to do an `ll -lsa` to see what hidden files have been created there then move them over to the new directory.)

Comment: @qweet: the password is now required for logging in, but that indeed makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your user have a home directory? You can check by `echo $HOME` and `grep user /etc/passwd`, the former echoing the user's directory, and the grep looking to see the home directory stored in the password file.

If it turns out your user doesn't have a `Home` directory set in `passwd`, then doing a `usermod -d /some/directory user` will force the change, and the user will then log in on that directory.

Also note that since your original home was set to `/tmp`, there may be some user setting files that will need transferring over to the new directory (like `.ssh` for example).

Comment: Note: usermod is not available in my installation of cygwin, so I had to restart the cygwin SSHD service to make this change take effect